# R - function which has a data frame parameter doesn't work

Tags: r, function, sapply

I make a simple code which can change the index number to name

```
change_name = function(x) {
  valid_user[match(x, valid_user$id),'name']
}
```

and apply this function to data.frame.

Data.frame name is 'ga.screen', and the column name is 'dimension1'.

```
ga.screen[, 'dimension1'] =sapply(ga.screen[, 'dimension1'], change_name)
```

It works well.

And next I want to make this code function which is be able to apply various case.

```
readable_user_id = function(data, col) {
  data[, col] = sapply(data[, col], change_name)
}
readable_user_id(ga.screen, 'dimension1')
```

This is totally same code but the latter one doesn't work!

Why this happens? Is this a `sapply` problem which doesn't work in function? or Is this `data.frame` problem which can't be passed as parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Your function should return the modified `data`, try

```
readable_user_id = function(data, col) {
   data[, col] = sapply(data[, col], change_name)
   data
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the return of function

Comment: perhaps the title does not really reflect your problem now? And the question may be closed?