# how to save the modifications which *apply family of functions did on data

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have list of data.frames.

```
> LoDFs <- list(data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3), y2=c(4,5,6)), data.frame(yA=c(1,2,3), yB=c(4,5,6)))

> LoDFs
[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

[[2]]
  yA yB
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018138/using-lapply-to-apply-a-function-over-list-of-data-frames-and-saving-output-to-f) I've found how to use `lapply` function to manipulate each data.frame separately. My goal is to change the column names in particular data.frame (both data.frames should have first column named `A` and second `B`). I've tried following:

```
> col.names <- c("A", "B")
> lapply(seq_along(LoDFs), function(x) {colnames(LoDFs[[x]]) <- col.names})
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B"
```

But it just returns the modification and didn't affect the particular data.frame:

```
> LoDFs
[[1]]
  y1 y2
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6

[[2]]
  yA yB
1  1  4
2  2  5
3  3  6
```

How to save the modifications which *apply family of functions did on data?

Comment: same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307870/r-function-which-has-a-data-frame-parameter-doesnt-work) about four questions down?

Comment: @rawr can you please modify mentioned example to my problem and post it as an answer? Based on linked question/answer I've tried to return value from function `lapply(seq_along(LoDFs), function(x) {colnames(LoDFs[[x]]) <- col.names; LoDFs})` but it did not worked as expected.

Comment: You have the right idea, but since lapply is acting on individual elements of LoDFs, you need to return that structure for each iteration. if you just have `; LoDFs})`, the replacement will be the entire list _for each iteration_. so you just need to return the modified elements `; LoDFs[[x]]})`

Comment: Guys I've up voted all answers and comments (but I can only pick up one answer). Seems that assigning results back to the variable is the only way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is `setNames`

```
lapply(LoDFs, setNames, c('A', 'B'))
# [[1]]
#  A B
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6

#[[2]]
#  A B
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6
```

If we need to modify in place, we can use `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`.

```
library(magrittr)
LoDFs %<>% 
      lapply(., setNames, c("A", "B"))
sapply(LoDFs, names)
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "A" 
#[2,] "B"  "B"
```

Comment: This is basically correct, BUT it is necessary to assign the result to old variable e.g. `LoDFs <- lapply(LoDFs, setNames, c('A', 'B'))`. I'm wondering if it is possible modify the data in place from `*apply`.

Comment: @WakanTanka  Updated the post.  Hope it helps

Comment: Seems that `magrittr` solution is similar to previous. This is first time I see `magrittr` code so maybe I'm wrong but the "magic" here lies in using `%<>%` instead of `>%` which basically assigns the result back to the left operand or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(LoDFs, 'names<-', c("A", "B"))
[[1]]
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  A B
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Comment: This is basically correct, BUT it is necessary to assign the result to old variable e.g. `LoDFs <- lapply(LoDFs, 'names<-', c("A", "B"))`. I'm wondering if it is possible modify the data in place from `*apply`.

Comment: @WakanTanka if you try the code you suggested you should find that it works. Any assignment in R can happen in place

Comment: @Chris yes it works, but I was wondering if it is possible directly from `*apply` function without overwriting original variable.

Comment: It is not overwriting anything. The original list is intact.

Comment: @PierreLafortune pardon my ignorance but I do not know what you mean. In your example when you print (without assigning) `LoDFs` then you can see that column names are the same as before. I would like to ask what does this `'names<-'` mean? Thank you very much.